# phalcon routes not working with nginx in windows.Each time it opens index page

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon

I open any other page it always opens up index page, routes are not properly working for phalcon app. whenever i try to open other page with different route it always open index page. My nginx.conf is below, Please check and suggest for correction.

```
server {

    listen       85;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    root   abc.example.com;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    autoindex on;

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

    location ~ \.php {

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # general static 
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|js|jpeg|png|ico|gif|txt|js|css|swf|zip|rar|avi|exe|mpg|mp3|wav|mpeg|asf|wmv)$ { 
    root abc.example.com; 
    } 



    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `$_GET['_url']` as the source of URIs instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? See: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/nginx.html

Comment: i've tried this but still it does not work for me.